# Incorrect Resharper Suggestion - "Merge Conditional Expression"

Tags: oracle, resharper

Given an oracle query which is returning a single string value, to get the value from the query I use the following two lines:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteOracleScalar();
return result != null ? ((OracleString)result).Value : null;
```

The "!= null" in this statement is underlines with the suggestion to "Merge Conditional Expression". If I accept the suggestion it changes it to:

```
return ((OracleString)result).Value;
```

Which throws an exception because the value returned will be null for a number of executions.

Is there anyway to use the ternary operator but not have this warning?

Note that if I change the code to:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteOracleScalar();
if (result == null)
    return null;
return ((OracleString)result).Value;
```

Resharper then first suggests that I "Convert to Return Statement" which just changes it back to use the ternary operator.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Looks like a R# bug. What version are you using?

Comment: JetBrains ReSharper Platform 6 Build 6.0.20141219.120158 on 2014-12-19 12:56:02Z
JetBrains ReSharper 9.0 Update 1 Build 9.0.20141219.130142 on 2014-12-19 13:12:31Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like exactly the bug identified in [RSRP-434610](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-434610):

- given original code that checks an object reference for nullity, and accesses a property of the object if the object reference is not null
- R# proposes a refactoring that *always* accesses the property, and will therefore fail when the object reference is null

The issue has a fix version of 9.1, which was released just a few days ago, although [watch out trying to upgrade from within VS](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/04/09/updating-from-previous-versions-of-resharper-to-9-1-from-within-visual-studio/).

Comment: I'm on ReSharper 2017.2.2 and it still doesn't seem to be fixed.